# Jumping to anchor on existing ajax/hash url

Tags: html, ajax, anchor

I have an ajax application that uses links like the following to serve appropriate pages...

```
www.mysite.com/#story=1
```

Depending on what link a user clicks on at www.mysite.com, I want the appropriate ajax-served page (e.g. www.mysite.com/#story=1) to load with the user directed to a page anchor.

The problem I'm having is that something like this doesn't work...

```
www.mysite.com/#story=1#pageHeadingAnchor1
```

(Because I'm assuming the initial hash I'm using to denote a page is preventing the second hash functioning as a page anchor).

Does anyone have an idea of how to deal with this combination of requirements (Ajax app hash plus page anchor hash)?  Seems like I might need a javascript solution to parse a second argument and then programatically jump to the anchor?  Or perhaps there's a better way?

Thanks for any thoughts at all.

Comment: why don't you use "query string" section? www.mysite.com?story=1#pageHeadingAnchor1

Comment: Thanks Roman, if you think that will work, I'm going to try it now - was actually thinking that perhaps the hash needed to be the first parameter of any kind after the main URL, but I'll be very happy if I'm wrong about that

Comment: access your "query string" section via location.search and "hash" section via location.hash

Comment: thanks Roman - you've given me enough to get this working without writing a custom piece of javascript!